# ASP. NET MVC Partial view always post null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a ASP.NET MVC Project .
I passed model to the partial view, it works like a charm .
But when i want to POST from the partial view, it always get null in model.
I tried to place post in view and in partial view, change the actionresult methods , but i don't have result.
How can i post from partial view ?
Model:

```
 public class MiazVM
    {
        public List<MiazListInd> MiazList { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Ogrn { get; set; }
        public Alert Alert { get; set; }
        public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

My View (Index.cshtml):

```
  @model LpuList.Models.MiazVM
...

        <div id="TableContent" Class="myTable">
            @Html.RenderPartial("Index_PartialView",Model)
        </div>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

My Partial view(Index_PartialView):

```
@model LpuList.Models.MiazVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_PartialView", "Miaz", FormMethod.Post))
{
      ...
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MiazLists.Count(); i++)
        {
       ...
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MiazLists[i].IdReq)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MiazLists[i].DateCh)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MiazLists[i].Status)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MiazLists[i].names)
                         @Html.ActionLink(Model.MiazLists[i].DateCh.ToString() + "  " + Model.MiazLists[i].Status.ToString() + "  " + Model.MiazLists[i].names, "EditReqMiaz", new { idL = Model.MiazLists[i].IdReq })
                        }
                      ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Подтвердить" class="btn btn-default" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отклонить" class="btn btn-default" />

}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index_PartialView( MiazVM miaz)
        {
           //MiazVM is null

            return View("Index", miaz);
        }
```

Comment: Possibly a model binding issue - If you inspect Request.Form in the debugger, can you see the form values there?

Comment: @Sam No, after post , it redirect to ActionResult( Index_PartialView) and MiazVm miaz is empty , all values in null

Comment: Not the model, The form state - You could verify what you're posting in the network inspector of you web browser... the thing of interest at the mo would be you actually end up posting to the endpoint

Comment: @Sam i checked in debugger in chrome , i see values in Form Data

Comment: You have not shown your model (does it contain public properties and not fields?). But what is the point of this - all you have is hidden inputs so nothing is editable

Comment: @StephenMuecke i add mode. As i understand i can make it only through Ajax

Comment: You do not need to use ajax. The code you have shown works fine, so its the code you have omitted that is the issue (and as a side note, your `return View("Index", miaz);` makes no sense - if you want to display the `Index` view, then your redirect to that method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to make post. But because partial view don't give it to controller , i need to pass model to controller

Comment: I know you want to make a post! Again, the code you have shown is correct and will work (even though it makes no sense at all to post back a whole lot of hidden inputs). If its not working for you, then it is due to code you have not shown us

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов may i ask why you have two submit buttons with the same name? Do you have an action method for each?

Comment: @ozum.e because i need decline and accept buttons on this page